# How to re-enable Cortana/Search after having turned it off?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I've turned off both search and search online buttons, but now the search isn't working at all (can't even type in), is there a way to reset that (useful) functionality?

Comment: Yeah;  You need to enable the search button.  Just reverse the process you follow to disable it.

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately, nothing is showing up when clicking in the search field like before

Comment: Yes; Because you disable it.  Just to be clear Cortana is used both in online and offline searches by design.  All you had to do was disable the online search part.

Comment: @Ramhound yes totally, but I messed up and disabled both and don't know how to reverse that

Comment: I don't know how you disabled it, so I gave a general solution, reverse the process you used to disable it in the first place.  If that does not work, Reset your installation, just select the "keep your personal files" option to minimize impact.

Comment: well it worked for a few seconds, the first button says "enable cortana for alerts, notifications, ..." so I think that's why I disabled it? now it stopped working again, I think the problem isn't even related to those button, I can see Cortana is my task manager

Comment: You didn't remove Cortana ( you really can't ) you just disabled.  You provided no information on how you disabled Cortana, so we can't tell you, how to reverse the process.

Comment: @Ramhound well it really worked a few minutes ago, I tried launching the screencapture from it, it worked then wanted to capture how Cortana wwas configured to show you, but basically both buttons are turned off, and it's not working now. Other useful information: I've windows10 Family in French

Comment: @Ramhound ended up restoring to a previous restoration point, it's working back, I'll carefully change things now